# gdb fails with "Unable to find Mach task port for process-id" error

Tags: macos, gdb

My app runs fine but gdb fails to debug it with the following error

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /path/to/app 
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 83767: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
```

I am on OS X Lion. GDB version is

```
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1752) (Sat Jan 28 03:02:46 UTC 2012)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".
```

Comment: I think this post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221448/emacs-24-and-gdb-6-3-on-mac-os-lion.

Comment: The instructions available here worked for me
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In Snow Leopard and later Mac OS versions, it isn't enough to codesign the `gdb` executable.

You have to follow this guide to make it work: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-69/docs/code-signing.txt

The guide explains how to do it for `lldb`, but the process is exactly the same for `gdb`.

Comment: Those instructions did not work for me on OSX 10.9.2 with MacPorts, but this did: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

Comment: It works! But can you please explain what the `sudo security add-trust` line is doing? Can I delete the `.cer` file from my desktop now?

Comment: ``codesign -s gdb_codesign `which gdb` `` helps after this guide

Comment: Or ``sudo codesign -s gdb_codesign `which gdb-apple` `` on macOS sierra.

Comment: Hmm, many misleading comments. The -s argument is the -p argument is the add-trust, therefore: codesing -s codeSign `which gdb` is the ticket.

Comment: The instructions from @simpler user worked on sierra - however restarting taskgated did not work - so a reboot was mandatory. Post reboot, you need to now use gdb. (Note called ggdb with mac ports). Having to use sudo here is not ideal. Any ideas how to avoid this ?

Comment: For the latest OS, [link](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/docs/code-signing.txt)  worked

Comment: When I first read this answer, I read "codesign" as "co-design", and was really confused until I realized it meant "code-sign".

Comment: @yuxuan, link doesn't work

Answer (score 166):

It works when I change to `sudo gdb executableFileName`! :)

Comment: Thanks.  This plus code signing were required to get gdb to work.  I gave gdb root access (as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476154/how-do-i-grant-root-access-to-a-user-application) so I didn't have to type sudo each time.

Edit - Found a better approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10441587/305149

Comment: Run it as root? Are you serious?
The worst "solution".

Comment: @Equidamoid Why would it be so bad to run `gdb` as root? I was just curious because It's just a debugger.

Comment: What would happen if you run it as a root? It's the code you wrote, and I don't understand the consequences

Comment: @COLDICE in general you don't want to run processes with escalated privileges (especially escalated to the top as root) since in general they don't need access to modify things on the system or open ports lower than 1024 (higher ports can be used by non system/non root users).  Even if you "trust" your own code it doesn't mean you didn't make a mistake that causes it to `rm -rf /`or something similiarly destructive where you overwrite some config/binaries that your computer relies on to start up and operate normally.

Comment: @AneilMallavarapu check out this to know what can happen https://gtfobins.github.io/gtfobins/gdb/

Comment: @shaunhusain This discussion shows insecure systems are. The most popular answer here suggests turning off security. The majority of users either over-grant privileges or turn off security entirely as a workaround. 

The problem stems from an overly complicated configuration. Creating a certificate, for instance, is amazingly complicated, forcing the user to understand how it works. Microsoft makes it especially difficult by using security by obfuscation, whereby users are not clued in error messages as to what specific resource is being denied access.

Answer (score 35):

You need to create a certificate and sign gdb:

- Open application “Keychain Access” (/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app)
- Open menu /Keychain Access/Certificate Assistant/Create a Certificate...
- Choose a name (gdb-cert in the example), set “Identity Type” to “Self Signed Root”, set “Certificate Type” to “Code Signing” and select the “Let me override defaults”. Click “Continue”.
  You might want to extend the predefined 365 days period to 3650 days.
- Click several times on “Continue” until you get to the “Specify a Location For The Certificate” screen, then set “Keychain to System”.
- If you can't store the certificate in the “System” keychain, create it in the “login” keychain, then export it. You can then import it into the “System” keychain.
- In keychains select “System”, and you should find your new certificate. Use the context menu for the certificate, select “Get Info”, open the “Trust” item, and set “Code Signing” to “Always Trust”.
- You must quit “Keychain Access” application in order to use the certificate and restart “taskgated” service by killing the current running “taskgated” process. Alternatively you can restart your computer.
- Finally you can sign gdb:

  `sudo codesign -s gdb-cert /usr/local/bin/ggdb`

  `sudo ggdb ./myprog`

Comment: note killing taskgated didn't restart the process. needed to: sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist

Comment: The above restarted taskgated - but it still did not work without a reboot on sierra, sadly.

Comment: What?  How bad has software become where the last restarting steps are not performed? At the very least, it could display an alert telling the user to restart.

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that you are not logged in as a root user (which you don't want). You need to create a certificate for gdb to be allowed access. Follow this tutorial and you should be good to go...

http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

If all else fails, just use: `sudo gdb executableFileName`

Comment: The tutorial ilnked here worked best. Just had to run `codesign -s gdb-cert $(which gdb)` To sign the `gdb` app.

Comment: Just confirming for anyone trying this on OSX 10.12.5, you have to both follow the steps outlined in the BuildingOnDarwin link AND run gdb after switching to root user.

Answer (score 7):

[This link](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/GDB_on_OS_X_Mavericks_and_Xcode_5) had the clearest and most detailed step-by-step to make this error disappear for me.

In my case I had to have the key as a "System" key otherwise it did not work (which not every url mentions).

Also killing `taskgated` is a viable (and quicker) alternative to having to restart.

I also [uninstalled MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/guide/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) before I started this process and uninstalled the current gdb using `brew uninstall gdb`.

Comment: This worked for me. +1 for reference that uses `brew`.

Answer (score 3):

I needed this command to make it work on El Capitan:

```
sudo security add-trust -d -r trustRoot -p basic -p codeSign -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ~/Desktop/gdb-cert.cer
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a really useful [guide](https://gist.github.com/hlissner/898b7dfc0a3b63824a70e15cd0180154) which solved my problem(OSX 10.13.6).

1. Open Keychain Access
2. In the menu, open Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Create a certificate
3. Give it a name (e.g. gdbc)

   - Identity type: Self Signed Root
   - Certificate type: Code Signing
   - Check: let me override defaults
4. Continue until it prompts you for: "specify a location for..."
5. Set Keychain location to System
6. Create a certificate and close assistant.
7. Find the certificate in System keychains, right click it > get info (or just double click it)
8. Expand Trust, set Code signing to always trust
9. Restart taskgated in terminal: killall taskgated
10. Run **`codesign -fs gdbc /usr/local/bin/gdb`** in terminal: this asks for the root password

Answer (score 2):

I followed [this](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/) tutorial, and everything is OK.

Answer (score 2):

On MacOSX lldb needs to be code signed. The Debug and Release builds are set to code sign using a code signing certificate named lldb_codesign.

```
If you don't have one yet you will need to:
- Launch /Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app

- In Keychain Access select the "login" keychain in the "Keychains"
  list in the upper left hand corner of the window.

- Select the following menu item:

    Keychain Access->Certificate Assistant->Create a Certificate...

- Set the following settings

    Name = lldb_codesign
    Identity Type = Self Signed Root
    Certificate Type = Code Signing

- Click Continue
- Click Continue
- Click Done
- Click on the "My Certificates"
- Double click on your new lldb_codesign certificate
- Turn down the "Trust" disclosure triangle

    Change:
        When using this certificate: Always Trust

- Enter your login password to confirm and make it trusted

The next steps are necessary on SnowLeopard, but are probably because of a bug
how Keychain Access makes certificates.

- Option-drag the new lldb_codesign certificate from the login keychain to
  the System keychain in the Keychains pane of the main Keychain Access window
  to make a copy of this certificate in the System keychain.  You'll have to
  authorize a few more times, set it to be "Always trusted" when asked.
- Switch to the System keychain, and drag the copy of lldb_codesign you just
  made there onto the desktop.
- Switch to Terminal, and run the following:

sudo security add-trust -d -r trustRoot -p basic -p codeSign -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ~/Desktop/lldb_codesign.cer

- Right click on the "lldb_codesign" certificate in the "System" keychain (NOT
  "login", but the one in "System"), and select "Delete" to delete it from
  the "System" keychain.
- Reboot
- Clean and rebuild lldb and you should be able to debug.

That should do it.
```

**[Note: - lldb is used in mac as gdb.]**

Answer (score 2):

These instructions work for OSX High Sierra and avoid running gdb as root (yuck!). I recently updated from OSX 10.13.2 to 10.3.3.  I think this is when gdb 8.0.1 (installed w/ homebrew) started failing for me.

I had difficulty with other people's instructions.  After different instructions, everything was a mess. So I started a fresh.  I more or less followed these [instructions](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin).

Clean the mess :

1. `brew uninstall --force gdb  # This deletes _all_ versions of gdb on the machine`
2. In `Applications` -> `Utilities` -> `Keychain Access`, I deleted all previous gdb certificates and keys (be sure you know what you're doing here!).  It's unclear if this is necessary, but since I'd buggered up trying to create those certificates and keys using other instructions I eliminated them anyways.  I had keys and certificates in both login and system.

Now reinstall gdb.

3. `brew install gdb`
4. Within `Keychain Access`, go to menu `Keychain Access`-> `Certificate Assistant` -> `Create a Certificate`
5. Check "Let me override defaults" and set

> ```
> Name : gdb-cert
> Identity Type: Self Signed Root
> Certificate Type : Code Signing
>
> [X] Let me override defaults
> ```

6. On 1st Certificate Information page:

> ```
> Serial Number : 1
> Validity Period (days): 3650
> ```

7. On 2nd Certificate Information page, I left all fields blank except those already filled in.
8. On Key Pair Information page, I left the defaults

> ```
> Key Size : 2048
> Algorithm : RSA
> ```

9. On Key Usage Extension page, I left the defaults checked.

> ```
> [X] Include Key Usage Extension
> [X] This extension is critical
> Capabilities:
> [X] Signature
> ```

10. On Extended Key Usage Extension page, I left the defaults checked.

> ```
> [X] Include Extended Key Usage Extension
> [X] This extension is critical
> Capabilities:
> [X] Code Signing
> ```

11. On Basic Constraints Extension Page, nothing was checked (default).
12. On Subject Alternate Name Extension page, I left the default checked and didn't add anything else.

> ```
> [X] Include Subject Alternate Name Extension
> ```

13. On Specify a Location for the certificate page, I set

> ```
> Keychain: System
> ```

14. I clicked Create and was prompted for my password.
15. Back in the `Keychain Access` app, I went to `System` and right clicked on `gdb-cert` and under dropdown menu `Trust`, I changed all the fields to `Always Trust`.
16. Rebooted computer.
17. (EDIT Sept 2023 on OSX 13.4.1).  Following these [instructions](https://superuser.com/a/1454510).  Create an `entitlements.xml` file

    local: Downloads $ cat entitlements.xml

    com.apple.security.cs.debugger
18. (EDIT Sept 2023) At the Terminal, I ran `codesign --entitlements entitlements.xml -fs gdb-cert $(which gdb)`.  I entered my password when prompted.
19. (EDIT Sept 2023) Check that it is signed

    local: Downloads $ codesign -vv $(which gdb)
    /usr/local/bin/gdb: valid on disk
    /usr/local/bin/gdb: satisfies its Designated Requirement
    local: Downloads $ codesign -d --entitlements - $(which gdb)
    Executable=/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/13.2/bin/gdb
    [Dict]
    [Key] com.apple.security.cs.debugger
    [Value]
    [Bool] true
20. At the Terminal, I ran `echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit`
21. I ran `gdb myprogram` and then `start` within the gdb console. Here, I believe, it prompted for me for my password.  After that, all subsequent runs, it did not prompt for my password.

Comment: Sadly, I did both top-voted answer and your answer, and still see the same error message.  I have macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4, and gdb 9.1.

Comment: @JaySullivan +1.  
I also have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird approach but it worked for me(MacOs HighSierra 10.13.3). Install CLion. It comes with gdb. Once run the gdb using Terminal. Copy the gdb program to your usr/local/bin/. No problem of signin, sudo etc.

Comment: That's a pretty smart move, but unfortunately as of today it doesn't work anymore — The gdb bundled with today's latest CLion keeps crashing with “Debugger process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)” (MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3 (20D91), CLion 2021.1 Build #CL-211.6693.114, /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/gdb/mac/bin/gdb version 10.1, SIP active)

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions here [Codesign gdb on macOS](https://gist.github.com/gravitylow/fb595186ce6068537a6e9da6d8b5b96d) seemed to resolve this issue, for me, on macOS High Sierra (10.13.3).