# Eclipse: what is MI command and why does it matter for running the C code?

Tags: eclipse

While trying to debug my C code snippet with Eclipse, it shows out the following popup.

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 4550: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 4550: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

Is there a solution for this matter? Also, I want to ask you if it actually bothers a lot to use Eclipse when writing a code in C. I never had this kinds of trouble when I first started learning Xcode, but now there seems to be quite a lot of things I should care with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Community Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/795327/)

> When CDT launches, it tries to set a breakpoint at main, so it will interrupt execution when your program starts. However, your target is already running so the breakpoint cannot be set and the whole things fails.
>
> You could simply tell your launch not to set that breakpoint and let it connect to your target.
> Go to: `Run->Debug Configurations...` and find your `launch configuration`. Then select the `Startup subtab`, scroll down and `uncheck "Set breakpoint at"` in the `"Runtime options"` subsection.

or See [gdb fails with “Unable to find Mach task port for process-id” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504377/gdb-fails-with-unable-to-find-mach-task-port-for-process-id-error)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but where can I find the 'launch configuration' thing? I reached the Debug configurations, and there does not seem to be the corresponding thing here.

Comment: I'm Using Eclipse Mars, by the way.

Comment: 'launch configuration'  means your configuration for CDT. See http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.debug.application.doc%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_new_run_config.htm