# Why doesn't lldb forward my environment variable anymore?

Tags: c, xcode, lldb

I'm working on a patch for FFmpeg and need to debug my code. I'm loading an external library, and in order to test different library versions, I have them in different folders. To select which one I want to use, I've been using `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib/dir ./ffmpeg` and that works okay. But when I try it within `lldb`, it crashes saying `dyld: Library not loaded` and `Reason: image not found`. This used to work pre-Xcode 7.1, but I just recently upgraded and it stopped working.

---

Here's my MVCE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char* str = getenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");
  if (str) puts(str);
  else     puts("(null)");
  return 0;
}
```

Running this program as follows produces the output:

```
$ ./a.out
(null)
$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp ./a.out
/tmp
```

That looks okay. But when I try to use lldb it fails:

```
$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp lldb ./a.out
(lldb) target create "./a.out"
Current executable set to './a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 54255 launched: './a.out' (x86_64)
(null)
Process 54255 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)
```

Trying to set the environment variable inside lldb works:

```
lldb ./a.out
(lldb) target create "./a.out"
Current executable set to './a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp
(lldb) run
Process 54331 launched: './a.out' (x86_64)
/tmp
Process 54331 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)
```

lldb version (it's from Xcode 7.1):

```
$ lldb --version
lldb-340.4.110
```

**Question:** Is this an intended new "feature," or is this a new bug in lldb (or am I totally crazy and this never used to work)? I'm quite positive lldb used to forward the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, so how come it isn't anymore?

---

Edit: This is on OS X 10.11.1.

Comment: Confirmed [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/lldb-dev@lists.llvm.org/msg00779.html) by Jason Molenda (who seems to be one of the lldb developers).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If this is on El Capitan (OS X 10.11), then it's almost certainly a side effect of System Integrity Protection. From the [System Integrity Protection Guide: Runtime Protections](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html) article:

> When a process is started, the kernel checks to see whether the main
>   executable is protected on disk or is signed with an special system
>   entitlement. If either is true, then a flag is set to denote that it
>   is protected against modification. …
>
> … Any dynamic linker (`dyld`)
>   environment variables, such as `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, are purged when
>   launching protected processes.

Everything in /usr/bin is protected in this fashion. Therefore, when you invoke /usr/bin/lldb, all DYLD_* environment variables are purged.

It should work to run lldb from within Xcode.app or the Command Line Tools, like so:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=whatever /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb <whatever else>
```

I don't believe that copy of lldb is protected. /usr/bin/lldb is actually just a trampoline that executes the version in Xcode or the Command Line Tools, so you're ultimately running the same thing. But /usr/bin/lldb is protected so the DYLD_* environment variables are purged when running that.

Otherwise, you will have to set the environment variable inside lldb as shown [in this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/lldb-dev@lists.llvm.org/msg00770.html):

```
(lldb) process launch --environment DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<mydylibpath> -- arg1 arg2 arg3
```

or using the short -v option:

```
(lldb) process launch -v DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<mydylibpath> -- arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Or, you can disable System Integrity Protection, although it serves a good purpose.

Comment: Yeah, this is on OS X 10.11.1. That's interesting. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: Thanks.  This solves my problem too (on El Capitan).  I've created an alias `alias lldb=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb` to alleviate the typing.

Comment: But I have sip disabled and I still have this issue. Weird. Damn I should have set up gdb instead, it's another one of those appley nonsense I guess

Comment: @MuhsinFatih Does invoking `lldb` using one of the other techniques work?

Comment: @KenThomases I am currently getting `Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 57838: (os/kern) failure`. I codesigned gdb but it still doesnt work, I am so pissed off right now. I will try to fix this. Look at this: https://opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-69/docs/code-signing.txt . It says "probably because of a bug
how Keychain Access makes certificates" and this doc is from snowleopard times and it is still not patched. goddamit my assignment is late because of apple bs. There is always something apple has done that ruins my time, always. sorry for rant it just made me feel better

Comment: btw that doc is for lldb but here it says it should fix for gdb as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512279/2770195

Comment: For whatever reason, setting the environment variable `process launch -v` doesn’t work for me either on lldb-1001.0.12.1/macOS 10.14.5. Instead I have to do explicitly set the environment via `env` before launching the process. Then it works.

Comment: In recent versions, LLDB seems to have moved to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/lldb`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable inside lldb once it is started.

```bash
$ lldb
(lldb) help env
Shorthand for viewing and setting environment variables.  Expects 'raw' input (see 'help raw-input'.)

Syntax: 
_regexp-env                  // Show environment
_regexp-env <name>=<value>   // Set an environment variable

'env' is an abbreviation for '_regexp-env'
(lldb)
```

So that

```bash
lldb ./a.out
(lldb) env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib/dir
(lldb) r
```

should work.
Tested with

```bash
$ lldb --version
lldb-1400.0.38.17
Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)
```