# How to use `env python3` and retaining the calling environment?

Tags: python, macos, shebang

I have a problem on OSX that `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is causing the environment variables, such as library paths (LD_LIBRARY_PATH for example), to be lost. On Linux it works correctly.

Reading the man page on `env` it doesn't appear it should be doing this. It should only be modifying the environment if I request it, and I am not.

What is a portable shebang line that preserves the environment?

*Note: I'm detecting the problem since a call to `subprocess.open` on one of my programs fails since it can't find one of the libraries. Yet if I start python interactively the same call works fine.*

Comment: Never mind, only *certain* env vars in the current shell are indeed not propagated it seems. I tested with a generic one and that worked.

Comment: This should only happen with `-` or `-i` passed, by a plain reading of the MacOS man page for `env`.

Comment: `env env`, for instance, shows all environment variables present in the inner instance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I tried with `pprint.pprint(dict(os.environ))` and can't seem to get *specific* environment variables to propagate. Not with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH =bar ./test.py` and not with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bar`, then `./test.py`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, hmm. Only as a shebang, I assume? `env python -c 'import os, pprint; pprint.pprint(dict(os.environ))'` works for me, likewise with `python3`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, with the first line being `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, and of course `import os` and `import pprint`.

Comment: Hmm. You're right, for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` we've got something interesting going on.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo env env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH` reproduces the issue too, while `FOO=foo env env | grep FOO` works as expected. Looks like some specific filtering.

Comment: I can reproduce it for DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH too. Interesting.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is explicitly documented to be discarded for setuid and setgid binaries, but that's not the case here. Yes, this is presumably an undocumented security-related behavior.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [El Capitan, make check, DYLD\_LIBRARY\_PATH](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/215030)

Comment: Also related: [Unable to set DYLD\_FALLBACK\_LIBRARY\_PATH in shell on OSX 10.11.1](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/212945). `env`, being a `/usr/bin` binary, is 'protected' in that some environment variables are stripped by the *System Integrity Protection*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the OS X [*System Integrity Protection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) at work; certain 'dangerous' environment variables such as `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and, as you discovered, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, are not passed to any binary with a `/usr/bin` or `/bin` path.

As such, `/usr/bin/env` never sees any of several environment variables and can't pass those on to the `python3` child process it spawns.

See several other posts on the subject:

- [Why doesn't lldb forward my environment variable anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587130/why-doesnt-lldb-forward-my-environment-variable-anymore)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212945/unable-to-set-dyld-fallback-library-path-in-shell-on-osx-10-11-1
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215030/el-capitan-make-check-dyld-library-path

If you are using `subprocess`, I'd check for the shebang line, extract the binary named after `env`, prefix your command with that binary, and bypass `env` altogether.

Comment: For my call to subprocess I could do that, but I have other scripts that call these ones (liek the build scripts) which have no control overhow they are called.

Comment: In any case this really sucks. This "feature" of OSX makes it very difficult to setup a development environment.

Comment: Yup, it makes things considerably harder; avoid using `/usr/bin/env` on scripts that need access to these variables, is the best I can do at the moment.