# No `/Builds` directory when using `gdb`

Tags: r, debugging, gdb

I am trying to use `gdb` with `R`. My `gdb` command seems to work fine with executable (written in `C`) but I encounter some issue when I use `gdb` in `R`.

I did

```
sudo R -d gdb
```

In case it matters, the reason for using the `sudo` command can be found in [this post (see most upvoted but not accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504377/gdb-fails-with-unable-to-find-mach-task-port-for-process-id-error) (I am on MAC OSX 10.11.3).

Right before the `(gdb)` prompt, it says:

> Reading symbols from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R...
>
> warning: `/Builds/CRAN-QA-Simon/R-build/mavericks-x86_64/R-3.2.3/src/main/Rmain.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
>
> (no debugging symbols found)...done.

I can confirm this file does not exist, I don't even have a `/Builds` directory. When I enter `run`, then a very long list of `[..] can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory` appears.

How can I debug this issue and make `gdb` work with `R`?

Comment: Don't spam tags! This is apparently not related to C or the bash.

Comment: I see 2 close votes for reason: `Questions seeking debugging help [..] must include the desired behavior [..]`. I am hoping to make `gdb` work with `R`. Please let me know if there is anything unclear.