# Abort trap 6: when running gdb on Mac OS

Tags: c, macos, gdb, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I have installed gdb on my Mac (with Mac OS 10.9 / Mavericks) via homebrew and codesigned it successfully.

Before starting a debug session with gdb I compiled my C-files like in this example:

```
gcc -g test.c -o test
```

Afterwards I called gdb:

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:Test User$ gdb ./test
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./test...Reading symbols from /Users/User/Test/test.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/test...done.
done.
```

Calling gdb commands like r or sta always results in the following error:

```
(gdb) r 
Abort trap: 6
```

What is the problem? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: The number 6 is (probably) the number which represents `SIGABRT`, which is usually only invoked by a call to `abort()`.

Comment: I have a different issue with `gdb` on Mac, but it might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504377/gdb-fails-with-unable-to-find-mach-task-port-for-process-id-error

Comment: Same problem, on OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan). My test program just adds 2 ints and returns 0- definitely no call to 'abort', and it runs fine w/o gdb. Any solutions?

Comment: I have tried several things that were proposed in other posts, including reinstallation of gdb and renewal of the certificate. But until now I wasn't able to get gdb to work...

Comment: @HerthaBSC I ran into the same problem. Any resolution on your side yet ? On OSX El Capitan 10.11.6. Compiled with `g++-7 (Homebrew GCC 7.3.0) 7.3.0` and using gdb `GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1`

Comment: Did you test it with a simple C program, like `printf("Hello\n");` or `printf("%d\n",a + b);` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest rebuilding `gdb` from the scratch. Instead of using some pre-built installations, you can always try to install it by yourself:

```
mkdir src
cd src
curl "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-8.0.tar.gz" -o gdb-8.0.tar.gz
tar zxf gdb-8.0.tar.gz
cd gdb-8.0
./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/usr/local
make
make install
```

Remember to sign it before you can use it: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gnat_ugn_unw/Codesigning-the-Debugger.html

This way, you can easily debug your code. For details of installation, take a look here: [Running GDB in macOS sierra](http://www.owsiak.org/running-gdb-in-macos-sierra/)