# gdb on mac os big sur 11.2.3 - Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 46414: (os/kern) failure (0x5)

Tags: macos, gdb, codesign

I create gdb.cert and run this:

```
killall taskgated
codesign -fs gdb.cert /usr/local/bin/gdb
```

but it does not work, gives error:

```
Starting program: <path> 
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 46414: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have already read this thread
[gdb fails with "Unable to find Mach task port for process-id" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504377/gdb-fails-with-unable-to-find-mach-task-port-for-process-id-error)

So did I and as a MacOs BigSur version 11.4 (20F71) user,I found the solution by running gdb with sudo. Just run it with sudo.